# What is the batch file command ": ="?

Tags: batch

I have the following batch script:

```
set logFile=%1_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%.log

set logFile=%logFile: =%
```

Does anyone know what the second line is all about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says replace all spaces with nothing.  If logfile was "This Is a Test" then after the second line, it would be "ThisIsaTest" (spaces equal nothing)

Answer (score 0):

MultiverseIT described what's going on.  For more detail on  environment variable substitution, look at the help for the SET command

```
Set /?
```

on the command line